# GLib-CRITICAL message on Linux

Tags: gtk, eclipse-rcp

i have a rcp application that run on windows and linux.
First off all, in windows all is working fine, but when i compile the app on linux i have a lot of this message outputs.

> GLib-CRITICAL **: 09:40:58.143: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in !=
> NULL' failed
>
> Gtk-WARNING **: 09:41:00.169: Negative content height -7 (allocation
> 1, extents 4x4) while allocating gadget (node button, owner
> GtkToggleButton)

the linux version is:
**Linux 3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64 GNU/Linux**

In the other hand i have problems with the visualization of the controls, maybe is releated with the other issue.

I try to change the --launcher.GTK_version 2 in the .ini file but the controls problems remains.

[login problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP04Y.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIfVQ.png)

Comment: First message looks like [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=548479)

Comment: thanks, greg, so if it's a linux bug on my side, there's nothing I can do. you could check the images, any recommendation for that problem? i host other question, maybe you can help me there too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63173212/toolbar-not-resize-after-ielementupdater